# What spells or other effects cause a creature to make a saving throw to avoid being knocked out?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, saving-throw, conditions

I saw that a hydra has "advantage on saving throws against being... knocked unconscious" and was curious as to what spells or effects would cause such a thing to happen. The only effect that came to mind is the *sleep* spell, which operates on hit points rather than a saving throw. What else can knock a creature unconscious?

Comment: For your purposes, do you include being reduced to zero hit points as a cause of unconsciousness?

Comment: Being reduced to zero hit points, as far as I know, bypasses any "save or be unconscious" mechanics by typically forcing the condition, and so I do not include this in the question. (Abilities that let a creature perform some kind of save to remain at 1 hit point automatically fail the 0 hit point requirement, since they avoid going to 0 hit points entirely.) If there is something here that I missed, I'd be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Spells

Fortunately D&D Beyond categorizes spells by applied conditions and lets you [filter by it](http://www.dndbeyond.com/spells?filter-class=0&filter-condition=15). Doing so lists *eyebite*, which applies unconscious as part of its Asleep mode, and *symbol*, which does so as part of its Sleep mode. In addition the spells *sleep* and *catnap* (not listed above) apply the condition, but not contingent on saving throws.

Whether the Slumber mode of *imprisonment* counts is unclear, the spell does not call out the unconscious condition, but asleep is often taken to mean unconscious. Ask your DM before making a sleeping <s>beauty</s> hydra.

### Monster abilities

In addition a number of monster traits cause the unconscious condition contingent on a saving throw, such as the [chasme](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/chasme)'s Drone:

> Any other creature that starts its turn within 30 feet of the chasme must succeed on a DC 12 Constitution saving throw or fall unconscious for 10 minutes. [...]

There's also the [Ogre Chain Brute](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/ogre-chain-brute)'s Chain Smash, the [Kamadan](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/kamadan)'s Sleep Breath, the [Beholder](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/beholder)'s (and [Gauth](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/gauth)'s and [Death Tyrant](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/death-tyrant)'s) Sleep ray, the Gentle Lullaby of a [Satyr with pipes](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/satyr-variant), and the Sleep Breath of Brass Dragons (and probably many others). Effects which cause the unconscious condition contingent on a poisoning (usually by failing the saving throw by 5 or more), such as the [pseudodragon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/pseudodragon)'s Sting presumably aren't valid.

---

To my knowledge there are no player character options which include the effect (outside the above spells, or summoning an applicable monster, nor any magic items (where it isn't part of a poison effect), but I welcome any additions I've missed.